# Fly-out menu hovering above action bar, but not hiding it

Tags: android, xamarin

I have created a fly-out (sliding) menu by an [example](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/04/19/fly-out-menu-xamarin-android/).

In example author uses `NoActionBar` attribute for activity to hide action bar.

But in my app I want to use actionBar's tabs (tabbed control, tab navigation) for navigation (like in a third picture).

Also in first and second pictures we can see a fly-out menu with desired view (screens from vk android app). Theirs menu hovers above action bar and they use tab control!

Last picture is my app. There menu is under action bar.

So, my question is: How can I make fly-out menu that will hover above action bar? But not with hiding action bar, so I will have possibility to use actionBar's tabs (it is impossible with NoActionBar attribute).

[image: fly-out menu] [image: fly-out menu hides] [image: tabbed navigation][image: my app]]

UPD: Found nice example here https://github.com/Cheesebaron/SlidingMenuSharp

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you looking into this example, it has all the needed information: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Your problem is that you inflate your navbar "under" the main activity (I guess, in a fragment).